# How to unwrap a word wrapped text?

Tags: algorithm

My system receives a string message. The sender applies a word wrap prior to my receipt. Assuming the max chars per line of the sending system's word wrapping algorithm is known, is it possible to correctly unwrap the text while preserving meaningful (user inserted) line breaks?

For example, here's some text. In the example, we will let a `*` denote a meaningful, user inserted line break and a `¬` indicate a word wrapping algorithm (system) inserted line break.

### Input

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed in elit¬
vitae rutrum. Mauris in fringilla nulla, id rutrum augue.*
Sed non venenatis diam. Nam porta diam eget ante tincidunt ornare. Nulla¬
iaculis auctor. Pellentesque nec diam id quam gravida sollicitudin. Donec¬
dictum libero vitae.*
*
Venenatis eleifend vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et*
*
Ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Quisque vitae tempus odio.
```

Ultimately what I'd like to do is "unwrap" the text while preserving the user inserted, meaningful line breaks.

### Expected output

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed in elit vitae rutrum. Mauris in fringilla nulla, id rutrum augue.*
Sed non venenatis diam. Nam porta diam eget ante tincidunt ornare. Nulla iaculis auctor. Pellentesque nec diam id quam gravida sollicitudin. Donec dictum libero vitae.*
*
Venenatis eleifend vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et*
*
Ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Quisque vitae tempus odio.
```

As you may see, the unwrapping algorithm is first tasked with classifying each line break as meaningful or system inserted. I'm able to get pretty close by examining the char count of the current line plus the char count of the first word of the next line. This is not perfect, however, as it would classify the line break on the sentence beginning with `Venenatis` as system inserted:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed in elit vitae rutrum. Mauris in fringilla nulla, id rutrum augue.*
Sed non venenatis diam. Nam porta diam eget ante tincidunt ornare. Nulla iaculis auctor. Pellentesque nec diam id quam gravida sollicitudin. Donec dictum libero vitae.*
*
Venenatis eleifend vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et*
Ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Quisque vitae tempus odio.
```

Thanks for any insight, Pete

Comment: Is there any chance to improve wrapping algo?

Comment: Is there any chance you could force the sending system to send again with a different maximum line length? That would allow your system to reevaluate lines it wasn't sure of.

Comment: Very interesting thought, but no.

Comment: I just pushed a library on PyPI to do exactly this: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/textunwrap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the general problem can be solved reliably when word-wrap and hard return line breaks are encoded the same. You can do an approximation:

- A line break that occurs before a word-wrap would have been forced (i.e., the next word would have fit on the line) is definitely a hard break. (This includes counting blank lines as hard breaks.)
- Otherwise, if the line ends with what appears to be a paragraph terminator, then it's more likely to be a hard break.

The tricky part of the second condition is computing the predicate "appears to be a paragraph terminator". A minimum requirement is that it end with an end-of-sentence punctuation sequence (".", "!", ".)", etc.). Additional requirements might be that the candidate hard break not split balanced pairs of punctuation marks (parentheses, paired quotation marks, etc.). (A corollary, at least in English, is that a sequence:

> open-quote, text, sentence terminator, open quote, text

is almost certainly a hard break.)

This all is obviously language-specific. It also assumes that there are no typos in the text itself (unbalanced quotes, etc.).

Even then, you're likely to get a number of false positives. I don't see any easy way to improve on it, though.

Comment: In the second condition you said "it's *more likely* to be a hard break"... are you sure? I think it would be at least equally likely that a sentence ended in the same place as a word wrap.

Comment: @nmclean - Here's an expansion of the second rule. Normally, a line that might be terminated because of word wrapping (i.e., the first word on the next line doesn't fit) is likely to end with a soft break. However, if the line also happens to end with what could be the end of a paragraph, then it's more likely to end with a hard break.

Comment: A break at maximum line length is very likely *not* a hard break when there is no paragraph terminator, but when there *is* a terminator, it's still equally likely that a sentence happened to end at maximum line length and the paragraph isn't finished. So yes, it's more likely than it is in the first case, but not more likely than not, so there is no safe assumption.

Comment: @nmclean - Yes, I think I made the point in my answer that this was not reliable. Do you have data to support the "equally likely...but not more likely than not" claim? Such data would be very useful in addressing OP's problem.

Comment: @TedHopp No real data, just intuition. If you look through a book or article, you'll find that, of sentences that end at the end of the line, it's easy to find examples of both ones that end a paragraph and ones that don't. Given that a paragraph has only *one* last line and *any number* of other lines, and that a terminator can appear *anywhere*, it seems more likely than not that a terminator at the end of a line would *not* indicate a paragraph break.

Comment: @nmclean - Okay, I get that argument. On the other hand, if I look back at the previous six comments to this answer so far, there are seven sentence endings at the end of lines, only one of which is due to word wrap. I don't see any reason that this proportionality would change much if the data were restricted to paragraphs that ended with full last lines. It certainly doesn't suggest equal likelihood to me.

Comment: @TedHopp Sorry, when I said "at the end of the line" I was meaning "at the maximum position" where wrapping would occur. The 6 comment endings wouldn't count because those lines are all too short. The proportionality would change considerably because the last line of a paragraph *always* ends with a sentence ending, but only rarely fills the whole line (just as rarely as a mid-paragraph sentence ending appears at the end of a line).

Answer (score 1):

If a take a file with no line breaks, just the pattern "x x x x x ..." and run it through the system once the system will insert line breaks to produce output with line breaks in it. If I treat that output as new input and run it through the system again it will not need to add any new line breaks and the output will be the same as the input.

So I have two different inputs (with and without line breaks) mapping to the same output. Therefore there is no absolutely correct way to work out which input was word-wrapped to produce any given output, because multiple inputs can map to the same output.

To go further with this I think you need some description of what input files from the user really look like that allows you to reject the theory that the user in fact happens to put in all the line breaks necessary and so the system never in fact needs to add any line breaks at all.

Comment: No, the unwrapping algorithm would not insert line breaks to the pattern `x x x x x ...`. The goal of the unwrapping algorithm is to remove line breaks, not insert them. If you ran both of your examples through the source system, however, my system's unwrapping algorithm would receive the exact same input.

Comment: If I have created two different examples which end up delivering the same input to the unwrapping algorithm, how is the unwrapping algorithm supposed to work out which of them is the right answer?

Comment: That's a good way to imagine the impossible problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this as a follow on to OCR'ing a book.  It was pretty easy to identify short lines which implied intended line breaks.  The tricky part was catching cases where the last line of a paragraph ran right up to the margin before an intentional line break.  I ended up having heuristics that helped me identify when the next line was likely to be the start of a new paragraph.  In the novel this included things like starting with a quote or a capital letter.  It wasn't perfect and I had to read it and correct the errors.  The first few passes I didn't get very far before finding problems and refining my rules.  It did save me time in the long run, but it was far from automated.